# rewriting product of power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> According to
>   $$\Lambda(\tau;q)=B_0(\tau)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i$$
>
> we define
>   $$[\Lambda(\tau;q)-B_0(\tau)]^m=\bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i \bigg]^m=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\mu_{m,n}(\tau)q^n,$$
>   with the definition
>   $$\mu_{1,n}(\tau)=B_n(\tau), \qquad n\geq1.$$
>   Then, it holds
>   $$[\Lambda(\tau;q)-B_0(\tau)]^{m+1}=\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\mu_{m+1,n}(\tau)q^n,$$
>   $$=\bigg[ \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\mu_{m,n}(\tau)q^n \bigg] \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i \bigg] = \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} q^n \bigg[ \sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\mu_{m,i}(\tau) B_{n-i}(\tau)\bigg]$$
>   which gives the recursion formula
>   $$\mu_{m+1,n}(\tau)=\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\mu_{m,i}(\tau) B_{n-i}(\tau)$$

I don't understand how do we get 
$$\bigg[ \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\mu_{m,n}(\tau)q^n \bigg] \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i \bigg] = \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} q^n \bigg[ \sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\mu_{m,i}(\tau) B_{n-i}(\tau)\bigg]$$
The expression in left hand side is a product of two power series. How can it be rewritten as the right hand side? I think there are some omitted steps and I wish to know them. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is an application of the *[Cauchy product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_infinite_series)* of two power series:
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{j=m}^\infty a_j q^j\right)\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k q^k\right)
&=\sum_{l=m+n}^\infty\left(\sum_{{j+k=l}\atop{j\geq m;k\geq n}}a_j b_k\right)q^l\\
&=\sum_{l=m+n}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=m}^{l-n}a_j b_{l-j}\right)q^{l}
\end{align*}

> We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> [\Lambda(\tau;q)-B_0(\tau)]^{m+1}&=\left[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i \right]^{m+1}\\
> &=\left[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i \right]^{m}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i \right]\\
> &=\left[\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\mu_{m,n}(\tau)q^n\right]\left[\sum_{i=1}^\infty B_i (\tau) q^i \right]\\
> &=\sum_{r={m+1}}^\infty\left[\sum_{{n+i=r}\atop{n\geq m; i\geq 1}}\mu_{m,n}(\tau)B_i (\tau)\right]q^r\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r={m+1}}^\infty\left[\sum_{n=m}^{r-1}\mu_{m,n}(\tau)B_{r-n}(\tau)\right]q^r\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n={m+1}}^\infty\left[\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\mu_{m,i}(\tau)B_{n-i} (\tau)\right]q^n\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the Cauchy product formula
- In (2) we replace $i$ with $r-n$ respecting the condtion: $n+i=r$. The upper limit of the inner sum is $r-1$ since $n+i=r$ and $i\geq 1$.
- In (3) we rename $n\rightarrow i$ and $r \rightarrow n$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is very helpful as you put it step by step and add comment to explain the steps. However, I want to make sure of something. When you write $\sum_{l=m+n}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=m}^{l-n}a_j b_{l-n}\right)q^{l}$, shouldn't it be $\sum_{l=m+n}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=m}^{l-n}a_j b_{l-j}\right)q^{l}$? At least, that's what I got from your answer.

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa: You're  welcome!    And yes, you're right. Typo corrected. Thanks!